# Safe mode.. mkdir

Tags: php, security, apache, safe-mode

I have a script that creates a directory "createddir" and sets the chmod to 777 (just for this test really..)

I then want to create subfolders, but then the script fails. because of safe mode.

Why was I able to create that first folder then? Is it because the folder now has different perms different from the gallery.php file which was uploaded via ftp?

Is there any way around this? This is a script for sale, I cannot ask people to simply disable safe mode as their host may not allow that.

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. 
The script whose uid is 10005 is not allowed to access 
/var/www/vhosts/yyy/httpdocs/zzz/files/createddir owned by uid 33 in 
/var/www/vhosts/yyy/httpdocs/zzz/files/gallery.php on line 254
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no way to solve it.
Either turn safe mode off or create these folders from FTP client

Answer (score -1):

As i can see and understand you don't have access to that folder. Try **chown**.
For help: **man chown**

EDIT:
I did not tested this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php
Take a look.

Comment: No - chown is restricted by safe mode. This is one of the many reasons safe mode is deprecated.

Comment: @symcbean though one can use chmod from shell